# Trying to center multiple div tags and keep them on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to center a contact form and a feedback form,
to get them to align horizontally i used float: left; for both of them
however i also want both forms to display horizontally center,

Every time I get them to display together horizontally they are stuck to 
the left and when ever I get them to center they're one above the other,

I am trying to do both of the above

I have tried using

```
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 500px;
```

I have also used float: left; to get them horizontally beside each other
but i cannot center them from that option either.

```
text-align: center;
```

seems to just center my text not my full div tags

please help, thanks

Comment: Give the outer container a defined width in pixels.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them all in a single parent DIV.

```
<div id="wrap"><!--content here --></div>
```

Give the parent a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto;`  :

```
#wrap{
margin: 0 auto;
width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `flex`* instead of `block` for `display` of your main container and `justify-content: center`*

*http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html

Keep in mind, the easiest way to maintain a horizontal line-up of elements is to ensure they are either `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`†. If your elements are stacking on top of each other, it is most likely they have `display: block;` The majority of form elements are by default inline as well as anchors and spans.

I used input tags instead of divs since they are inline, but if you want to use divs still then make each of them like so:

`div { display: inline-block; }`

The selector "div" can of course very according to your code (which is oddly absent) -_-

†http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

Made an additional demo with 2 fieldsets #contact and #feedback.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pET6ZsG3IKQITXqnXBZY?p=preview

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
}
#bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
input {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="bar">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
  <input value="INPUT">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is what you are looking for, fairly responsive too.

The two divs are centered within a wrapper div.

https://jsfiddle.net/jp1p1dq4/2/

Here is the markup;

```
<div id="divWrap">
<div class="halfDiv left"></div>
<div class="halfDiv right"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
#divWrap{
  width:auto; 
  margin:none;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#3f3f3f;
  align-content:center;
  padding:1em 0;
}
.left{
  background-color:#696969;
}
.right{
  background-color:#939393;
}
.halfDiv{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  margin: 0 2%;
  width:46%;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use display: table instead of display : block

```
display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
```